# DevExpress how to get parent GridView column to show a sum of a child GridView's column

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I have a model that has a list of models inside of it (simplified):

```
public class GridItemModel {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<GridItemInventoryModel> Inventory { get; set; }
}

public class GridItemInventoryModel {
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

I bind my data to the grid view like so (`gridItems` is a list of GridItemModel):

```
gridItems = dal.GetInventoryGrid().ToList();

gridInventory.DataSource = gridItems;
```

`gridInventory` is the DevXpress GridControl.

I've implemented these methods from the gridview:

```
    private void gridView1_MasterRowGetChildList(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.MasterRowGetChildListEventArgs e) {
        GridItemModel i = (GridItemModel)gridView1.GetRow(e.RowHandle);
        e.ChildList = new BindingSource(i, "Inventory");
    }

    private void gridView1_MasterRowGetRelationName(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.MasterRowGetRelationNameEventArgs e) {
        e.RelationName = "Inventory";
    }

    private void gridView1_MasterRowGetRelationCount(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.MasterRowGetRelationCountEventArgs e) {
        e.RelationCount = 1;
    }

    private void gridView1_MasterRowEmpty(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.MasterRowEmptyEventArgs e) {
        GridItemModel i = (GridItemModel)gridView1.GetRow(e.RowHandle);
        e.IsEmpty = i == null;
    }
```

Which then makes my grid look like so:

[image]

When using various filters some of the items in the child view are hidden, and I need the Quantity on the end column to reflect the sum of only the visible child records.

I've so far overridden `gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData` as explained here:
http://www.wenda.io/questions/5156824/how-to-make-the-sum-of-each-detail-gridview-and-populated-in-the-footer-of-maste.html
But I don't have DataRows they can only be cast to GridItemModel.

And I have access to my items within the grid:

```
GridView view = sender as GridView;
if (e.Column.FieldName != "colCalcQty") return;
if (!e.IsGetData) return;
var list = (view.DataSource as IList);

var item = (list[e.ListSourceRowIndex] as GridItemModel);
```

But item.Inventory always shows all the inventory models instead of those that the filter hasn't removed.

I have access to both the Parent and Child grids via gridView1 and gridView2 respectively.

How am I able to create a summed column from the visible child views quantity field with the setup I have?

**Edit:**
I filter my view a couple of different ways, firstly I have ShowAutoFilterRow enabled on my grid but this only filters the parent records.

Then I have a combobox elsewhere on my form which on the selected index changed event calls this code:

```
        InventoryLibrary.DataTransferObjects.SimpleLocationModel location = ((ComboBoxEdit)cbeLocationsFilter).SelectedItem as InventoryLibrary.DataTransferObjects.SimpleLocationModel;
        InventoryLibrary.DataTransferObjects.SimpleLocationModel subLocation = ((ComboBoxEdit)cbeSubLocationsFilter).SelectedItem as InventoryLibrary.DataTransferObjects.SimpleLocationModel;

        string itemFilterString = "";
        string locationFilterString = "";


        if (location != null) {
            itemFilterString += String.Format("[LocationNames] LIKE '%{0}%'", location.Name);
            locationFilterString += String.Format("[LocationAndSublocation] LIKE '%{0}%'", location.Name);
        }

        if (subLocation != null) {

            if (location != null) itemFilterString += " AND ";
            itemFilterString += String.Format("[LocationNames] LIKE '%{0}%'", subLocation.Name);

            if (location != null) locationFilterString += " AND ";
            locationFilterString += String.Format("[LocationAndSublocation] LIKE '%{0}%'", subLocation.Name);
        }

        gridView1.ActiveFilterString = itemFilterString;
        gridView2.ActiveFilterString = locationFilterString;
```

This is what filters down the detail views when `gridView2.ActiveFilterString` has a filter string applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get `DetailView` for current row and sum quantity of all `DetailView`'s filtered rows. To get `DetailView` you can use [`GridView.GetDetailView`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_GetDetailViewtopic) method and to get filtered rows you can use undocumented `GridView.DataController.GetAllFilteredAndSortedRows` method. If `DetailView` is null then you need to get **«DevExpress filter engine»** and use it with your `GridItemModel.Inventory` list. You can get this engine from `DevExpress` controls such:

- GridControl
- PivotGridControl
- FilterControl
- e.t.c.

Here is example for `gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData` event and `GridControl` as **«DevExpress filter engine»**. For this example you need to add additional `GridControl`<sup>0</sup> and add a `GridView`<sup>1</sup> to this control.

```
if (!e.IsGetData || e.Column.FieldName != "colCalcQty")
    return;

var rowHandle = gridView1.GetRowHandle(e.ListSourceRowIndex);
var view = gridView1.GetDetailView(rowHandle, 0);

int quantity = 0;

if (view == null)
{
    var gridItem = (GridItemModel)e.Row;

    gridControl2.DataSource = gridItem.Inventory;
    gridControl2.RefreshDataSource();
    gridView3.ActiveFilterString = gridView2.ActiveFilterString;

    view = gridView3;
}

foreach (var row in view.DataController.GetAllFilteredAndSortedRows())
{
    var gridItemInventory = (GridItemInventoryModel)row;
    quantity += gridItemInventory.Quantity;
}

e.Value = quantity;
```

Also you need to refresh your `MainView` after setting a filter to `DetailView`:

```
gridView2.ActiveFilterString = "Some filter criteria";
gridView1.RefreshData();
```

<sup><sup>0</sup> - `gridControl2` in example.</sup>
<sup><sup>1</sup> - `gridView3` in example.</sup>

Comment: This is is so very close, The quantity column is correct initially (e.g. 100). Then I filter my results and the Qty column is then wrong(still 100), if I expand the detail view the qty column then updates to right number(e.g. 50).

Do you know how I can get the quantity to be updated without having to expanded the detail record?

Comment: @Smithy How do you filter your detail view before expanding?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how it is done in detail but basically I call:  gridView2.ActiveFilterString = locationFilterString;

Comment: @Smithy You need to apply filter to your `GridItemModel.Inventory` list by using «DevExpress filter engine». Look at my updated [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27957921/1805640).

Comment: This is fantastic! How come I need the second GridControl? Is it to copy my data + filters into the new GridView to preload the results?

Comment: @Smithy Yes, it is only for count quantity in background. I used `GridControl` just for example. You also can try with `PivotGridControl` or with `FilterControl`.

Comment: Much appreciated, thank you very much for your continued help :)